# Drools reusability issues

Tags: drools

I'm evaluating JBoss Drools currently and would like to seek help from the community regarding the reusability issues I've identified so far:

1. To create knowledgebase, one has to import .drl file/s but if I only want to use a subset of rules from a .drl file, other than forming rule groups (using agenda-group or RuleFlowGroup), are there other ways to do this? Using rule groups can easily make the rule definition messy, imagine you have 10 different subsets of rules with overlapping, that's 10 rule groups...
2. Is there any way to insert facts into the rule knowledgesession dynamically? It seems to me all the required facts/data need to be inserted into the session before firing the rule engine, creating performance bottlenecks... E.g., If one of the facts resides in database, the engine cannot be fired unless the fact from database is drawn. It would be better if the engine can process other facts first and when the fact from database is ready, insert it dynamically into the session.

Answer (score 1):

1. Good way of doing this is using agenda-group. Other way is, separate your rules package wise.
2. As I under stand your question, you can use Fact Handles.

   Use `StatefullKnowledgeSession` here.

   FactHandle objHandle = ksession.insert( fact );

After while,  when your facts are ready from database, you can modify the facts in current  running session.

```
ksession.update(objHandle, newFactObject(of same class))
```

For more details, go to http://downloads.jboss.com/drools/docs/5.1.1.34858.FINAL/drools-expert/html_single/index.html chapter 2.1.2. Stateful Knowledge Session.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your prompt reply :)

For 1. I'm hoping to find a way to choose rules to fire programmatically - I will have to modify the rule files if use agenda-group. Separating rules package can be clumsy as I have to change the classpath (to load the rules) of the affected Java classes.

For 2. Thank for sharing about the facthandle. But if the facts from database came in after the knowledge session completed its run? In that sense, I will still have to wait for all the data are available before firing the rule engine [correct me if I'm wrong].

Comment: Hi,  
  1. separate rule by package doesn't mean that you put your rules in different packages. Rule  package is just a name of group that contains multiple rule. You can build different rule base for different purpose with different rule packages(one or more). 2. StateFullKnowledgeSession require to dispose manually. So until you don't have your facts from database, you can keep session running. An then dispose it manually. If it takes more time to get facts from database then you should create new session.

Comment: For 1. Yup I understood the rule package though I prefer more granular control over the firing of rules (e.g., using Java code, load a rule file and fire just this rule). Thanks, I think I got the idea :)

For 2, I've overlooked the point about StateFullKnowledgeSession require to dispose manually, saw also that knowledge sessions can be persisted, probably going with the design of persisting sessions until facts from database are ready then resume sessions.